# How to build a .deb file from apt-get packages?

Tags: 14.04, apt

I'm in need of deploying the same software over and over on multiple systems.

*How can I build a .deb file from `apt-get` packages like `ia32-libs` in Ubuntu so I don't have to download this software on each and every system?*  (and wait while doing so and consuming bandwidth?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty easy: go to http://packages.ubuntu.com and download them there, put them on a USB stick and then deploy them using the USB stick!

When you double-click the .deb files, the software center should open automatically and download any additional packages needed while you're doing this.

If this happens, on that machine go to `/var/cache/apt/archives/`,copy them on your USB stick as well and on the next machine, install them from the USB stick...